# clj-http/get url {:as :json} doesn't work in script but in REPL

Tags: json, clojure, clj-http

I'm experimenting with Clojure and Leiningen.
I was successful in executing to following line in the REPL:

```
(print (:body (client/get "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=CAD" {:as :json}))
```

I created a project with `lein new http`. When I run the following lines witn `lein run` then the coercion to JSON doesn't work. It simply prints a correct JSON string.

```
(ns http.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
  (:use clojure.pprint))

(defn -main
  []
  (print
    (:body
      (client/get "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=CAD" {:as :json}))
```

the output of the script is

```
{"amount":"306.89","currency":"CAD"}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: what version of clj-http are you using.  Also, what output are you expecting?

Comment: I've got clj-http 2.0.0 configured in my project.clj. But I suspect that the REPL pulls a different version. I don't how to check that. The expected out put would be a Clojure map {:amount "306.89", :currency "CAD}

Comment: [typos fixed] I've got clj-http 2.0.0 configured in my project.clj. But I suspect that the REPL pulls a different version. I don't know how to check that. The expected output would be a Clojure map {:amount "306.89", :currency "CAD}

Comment: [clj-http "1.1.2"] has the behavior you want.

Comment: thank you. That was it it. Seems the 2.0.0 version has a problem. If you'd like to put an official answer in I'll accept and you can earn the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what changed, but [clj-http "1.1.2"] has the behavior you want.

Answer (score 4):

As it turned out there was a breaking change with clj-http version 2.0.0.
Now one has to list explicitly the optional dependencies in `project.clj`.
After I added

```
[cheshire "5.5.0"]
```

to my list of dependencies the program worked as expected.
Please see the documentation for the change [here](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#optional-dependencies).